# JQuery: Create a div as parent and add existing elements to it

Tags: jquery, append, addition, parent, children

I want to create a new div(row) which contains everytime 4 `<a>`(incl. the children of `<a>`) tags and starting before the first `<a>`tag.
**Here is how it looks right now:**

```
<div class="container" id="cont">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">My Page Header</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
</div>
```

**But it should look like this:**

```
 <div class="container" id="cont">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">My Page Header</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <a>....</a>
        <a>....</a>
        <a>....</a>
        <a>....</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <a>....</a>
        <a>....</a>
        <a>....</a>
        <a>....</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

and so on...The `<a>` tags do not have any ID's they only contain some Images.

How do I manage to do this with JQuery?

Keep in mind I am completely unexperienced with JQuery!

My code so far:

```
$("#cont").children("a").each(function(index) {
if (index % 4 == 0) {
    $('<div id="abc' + index + '">Test</div>').insertAfter(".row");
}
```

});

Comment: Typically you would do this in PHP (or whatever server side language generates the output), are you able to do it before/during the output? `<?php echo ($counter%4) '</div><div class="row">':''; ?>` - Outputting a new row every four rows using a PHP mod operator and loop counter.

Comment: I have added the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mz_arain08/qy7g39q0/2/)

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var mycontent = '';
        $("#cont").children("a").each(function (index) {
            var cc = $(this).html();
            if (index % 4 == 0) {
                mycontent += '</div><div id="abc' + index + '">';
                mycontent += "<a href=''>" + $(this).html() + "</a>";
            }
            else {
                mycontent += "<a href=''>" + $(this).html() + "</a>";
            }
        });
        $("#cont").find('a').remove();
        $("#cont:first .row").append(mycontent);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="cont">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">My Page Header</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I needed, I just had to adapt it because I had some attributes in my <a> tags, now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
var $row = $("<div class='row'></div>");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    $link = $("<a></a>");
    $row.append ($link);
}
$row.appendTo(".container");
```

This will make a row with four links in it.

Answer (score 0):

better solution

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
        let aTag =  $(this).find('a');
        for(var i = 0; i < aTag.length; i+=4) {
            aTag.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll("<div class='row'></div>");
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="cont">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">My Page Header</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
    <a>....</a>
</div>
```